# Entity Framework 1:1 mapping foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

My entity AppUser has an optional UserProfile, and UserProfile as a required AppUser. I would like to have a foreign key to each other.

```
public class AppUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
        public int? UserProfileId { get; set; }
    }

public class UserProfile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string SomeUserProfileValue { get; set; }

        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    }
```

I got this mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasOptional(x => x.UserProfile).WithRequired(x => x.AppUser)
```

This generate the following migration. I notice there is no foreign key from AppUser to UserProfile. Also the foreignkey in UserProfile is defined on UserProfile.Id ... I want it on UserProfile.AppUserId.

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AppUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    UserProfileId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserProfiles",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    SomeUserProfileValue = c.String(),
                    AppUserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AppUsers", t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Id);

    }
```

So I tried to change the mapping configuration as follow

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasOptional(x => x.UserProfile).WithRequired(x => x.AppUser)
                .Map(c => c.MapKey("AppUserId"));
```

But now when I try to add the migration i get the error:

```
AppUserId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'AppUserId' is already defined.
```

This seems to complain that I have a field AppUserId already defined in my model.

This is how we define our entities, we always include both the class and the id fields, gives more flexibility as to which to use under different circumstances.

So I'm a bit stuck here... is there any way to have this 1:1 bidirectional relation while having both class and the id fields defined in the model ?
And why there is no nullable foreign key generated in the AppUser table ?

Answer (score 0):

I've generally found better results with DataAnnotations, myself.  So:

```
public class AppUser
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? UserProfileId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey = "UserProfileId"]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeUserProfileValue { get; set; }

    public int AppUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey = "AppUserId"]
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This give me error: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'UserProfile' and 'AppUser'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: And if I add Required attribute on UserProfile.AppUser, I then get: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'UserProfile' on type 'AppUser' is not valid. The foreign key name 'UserProfileId' was not found on the dependent type 'UserProfile'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: Sry, bout that. Away from PC at the moment.  @GuillaumeMorin, Try adding [Required] to UserProfile.AppUserId instead.